# Cant get my program to sort json data into lists

Tags: python

```
import urllib.request
f = open('katastritunnused.txt', 'r')
list0=[]
list1=[]
for line in f:
   katastritunnus = line
   maaamet_url ='https://geoportaal.maaamet.ee/url/xgis-ky.php?ky=41201:004:0067&out=json'.format(line)
   url = maaamet_url.replace("\n","")
   pindala = {'key1': 'value1'}
päring = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
a= (str(päring.read())).split(" ")
index= a.index('"pindala":')
print (a[index+1].replace('"',""))

t.close()
```

I need my code to make a list from data gathered from this url but for some reason im getting an error. And then i would like it to include a request function from the data gathered (in this stylee (xxxxx:xxx:xxxx)) from this link but i have no idea on how to do it. (yes, i googled) please help me out here

1. 17001:001:0001
2. 17001:001:0002
3. 17001:001:0003
4. 17001:001:0004
5. 17001:001:0005
6. 17001:001:0006
7. 17001:001:0007
8. 17001:001:0009
9. 17001:002:0001
10. 17001:002:0002

Comment: Please add details like what is the error

Comment: well, you're opening f and closing t. and you shouldnt use ascii characters in variable names: "päring", use "paring" And youre not adding anything to the lists. Youre simply looping through your file, but not doing anything with it.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Desktop\proge\ÜL7\ül71.py", line 13, in <module>
    index= a.index('"pindala":')
ValueError: '"pindala":' is not in list

Comment: But how do i get it to take data from the url and clean it and then save it into a list

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the error you are facing. But the response JSON has keys with different casing and encoding. And yes, parsing a JSON response can be with a JSON library, not with string processing.

This example works fine for your case

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://geoportaal.maaamet.ee/url/xgis-ky.php?ky=41201:004:0067&out=json')
json_response = response.json()
print(json_response["1"].get("Pindala"))
```

Generated an output:

```
57999 m²
```

Response from the URL you used is like:

```
{
    "1": {
        "Maakond": "Pärnu maakond",
        "Omavalitsus": "Lääneranna vald",
        "Asustusüksus": "Lihula linn",
        "Tunnus": "41201:004:0067",
        "Lähiaadress": "Jaama tn 9",
        "Sihtotstarve 1": "Ühiskondlike ehitiste maa 100%",
        "Sihtotstarve 2": "-",
        "Sihtotstarve 3": "-",
        "Pindala": "57999 m²",
        "Haritav maa": "3425 m²",
        "Rohumaa": "10582 m²",
        "Metsamaa": "-",
        "Õuemaa": "1989 m²",
        "Ehitiste alune maa": "-",
        "Muu maa": "42003 m²",
        "Veealune maa": "-",
        "Registreerimise aeg": "12. jaanuar 2006. a.",
        "Muudatuse registreerimise aeg": "30. aprill 2020. a.",
        "Registriosa": "2110132",
        "Kinnistuspiirkond / jaoskond": "Tartu Maakohtu kinnistusosakond",
        "Mõõdistamise kuupäev": "-",
        "Mõõdistaja": "Omavalitsus",
        "Mõõdistamisviis": "kaardi ja plaani alusel",
        "Hinnatsoon": "<table><tr><td><a href=\"http://www.maaamet.ee/hv/411.pdf\" target=\"_blank\"><u><b><font color=\"#0000FF\">H0412001</b></u></a></td><td> 100% </td></tr></table>",
        "Viljakustsoon": "<table><tr><td><a href=\"http://www.maaamet.ee/hv/411.pdf\" target=\"_blank\"><u><b><font color=\"#0000FF\">V0411020</b></u></a></td><td> 100% </td></tr></table>",
        "Katastripidaja märked": "Pindala on ebatäpne (01.07.2018)",
        "Omandivorm": "Munitsipaalomand"
    }
}
```

Make sure the keys are fine with your code.
Also, You are using format in the line

```
maaamet_url ='https://geoportaal.maaamet.ee/url/xgis-ky.php?ky=41201:004:0067&out=json'.format(line)
```

But there is no placeholder `{}` for the formatter to replace the content.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' I assume i dont have pip? but i have python 3 and it should come with it.

Comment: You can install requests with pip.

Comment: But how do i get data for everythine else by just having their (xxxxx:xxx:xxxx) numbers in a txt file? I put the data into the first post

Comment: read those numbers to a list and iterate this logic for everything!